# How Can I Center the "Confirm Window" Alert in the Center of the Page Using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am facing Issue with "Confirm Window" Alert...I need to center the "Window.Confirm" alert in the Center of the Page, But it is showing at the Top of the Page..
Can Anyone Help me How Can I do that, Here In the Delete Function I am Dispatching an Action through Redux, Can Anyone Please Help me in this, Thanks in Advance..

Delete Function with Confirm Window :

```
const deleteData =(productId) =>{
      if(window.confirm('Are You Sure, You want delete?')){
        dispatch(allActions.deleteData(productId))
      }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to customize the appearance or position of the native browser UI elements which appear when invoking `window.confirm`. They are not part of the DOM. You can write your own or use an existing module which provides equivalent functionality.

Comment: Oh OK , How Can I create that and Update my Action Over there... Do you have Sample Code for that?

Comment: @sundeep Unless there is an exceptional case, modal dialogs are generally not a positive UX pattern. You might consider displaying the confirmation message and confirmation button in the product component after the user selects the Delete action.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the position of `window.confirm`.

You can either create a modal component in React or use one of the existing npm packages like [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal).

Comment: Oh OK , How Can I create that and Update my Action Over there... Do you have Sample Code for that?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. A simple google search for showing confirmation modal dialog in react will show you the different ways this can be implemented. You can choose the one that suits your need